# computed column calling a stored procedure

Tags: c#, datagridview

I hope you can give a hand with this.

How to get a computed column in a `datagridview` when the data for that column should come from a `storedProcedure`. It's just one value that is returned with that `sp`. Im not sure if that's is possible or I should include a function `sql` to perform that task in the `sql` string?

Answer (score 0):

How to do it programatically..
u click on the button that says load for instance..
here is an example of typical code to load a stored procedure..
 u can move the code to page_load instead of Button1_click..
am just posting the important snippets of code..

```
public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page {
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Local-host;Initial 
                                      Catalog=HRM_Login;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Label2.Visible = true;
                GridView1.Visible = true;

                sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "GetStudentName";
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Studentid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value 
                                          = Int32.Parse(txt_studentid.Text);
                sqladp.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
                sqladp.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
    }

well u can try
GridView1.DataSource = ds; instead of GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I've got it ! But what if one column must be populated on  fly getting data from the SP I mean, the rest of the columns get data from DS [a table] and just one from a [stored procedured]. Is it possible ? .

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc.aspx

i guess u will hv to work hard with dataset.Merge() to merge 2 different datasets into 1. an easier implementation probably would be to create a new stored procedure with the merged dataset and bind to the newer dataset but it might not solve the purpose in case you really have 2 datasets which have equally similar schema and the real purpose u r merging is to refresh the datasets at the front end which is a complicated job. all the best with this tough requirement